# Is it possible to render a user control inside of a generic handler (ashx)?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, ashx

There might be a better way to get the result I'm looking for.  Basically I have a page that dynamically loads content into a div using jquery.load().

So far it works great for static content, but now I have a repeater that I want to be able to include in this content.  So I wanted to use a generic handler (maybe a webservice) to dynamically generate the rendered html of the user control and insert (or append, or load) it into the div.

So far I've had no luck.

Initially I tried this method

```
        UCPeople ucPeople = new UCPeople { RoleType = (roleType.ToLower() == "board" ? RoleTypes.Board : RoleTypes.Executive) };

        TextWriter myTextWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myTextWriter);

        ucPeople.RenderControl(myWriter);

        return myTextWriter.ToString();
```

Which just returns an empty string.

So then I tried adding the control to a page instance, and it still came out blank.

Then I tried to load the userconrol into the new page instance with this.

```
var page = new Page(){ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Disabled };
            UCPeople ucPeople = (UCPeople)page.LoadControl("~/our-company/people/UCPeople.ascx");
```

That seemed to get further, but the usercontrol throw an error because it's not in a form.
When I checked the form was null for that page.  So I figured I needed to create an instance of the page, and I tried it two different ways.

```
        var p2 = (Page)PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance("~/our-company/people/peopleTest.aspx",
                                                    "~/our-company/people/peopleTest.aspx", context);
        var p = (Page)System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/our-company/people/peopleTest.aspx", typeof(Page));
```

Both still yielded a null form.

I'm out of ideas.  Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you mixed things. If you need controls you need use Page. Handler are in the list of base classes of Page and have less functionality. Handler are common use to serve a very base thing like a file, an image, an json data. Why exactly you are using a Handler?

Comment: I don't want a page.  I want just the rendered html for the single control.  A handler can return plain text and be used asynchronously to return html.  Alternatively I can use a webservice to return the necessary markup. However, you're focusing on the wrong part of the question.

Comment: Ok. What about `return myTextWriter.ToString();`? Where are you returning? Because `ProcessRequest` from handler (where I think you need to act in this case) returns `void`. Maybe you need this: `HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(myTextWriter.ToString());HttpContext.Current.Response.End();`